# root login password when I never set it?

Tags: command-line, login, password, root, ruby

Sorry for too many duplicate questions about this. But I don't think any of the answers to these kind of question has the solution for me.

As some users might have asked, how to set root login password when I never set it at installation?

I'm new to ubuntu, and although I used it mainly just for browsing and writing documents, I never use it beyond the standard user wall. Now I'm going to use it to learn develop ruby. My friend helps me over email with the terminal commands sequence needed to set up ruby and rails and whatsoever needed on my ubuntu.

But when I run the first command `apt-get update`, the OS tells me that it can't lock something something, and finally hinted "are you a root?" Just FYI, this ubuntu is a clean installation on virtual machine, and I just set one account name with one password at the installation. I never get asked about a root password.

I googled about how to run a command as root, and I found that I need to use the `sudo` command. But when I add the `sudo` prefix before the `apt-get update` command, I get asked for root password. I used my first and only account password, and it didn't work.

from what I've read on the internet, I get this conclusion and confusion:

- the first user you created on the installation IS a default admin. -- but why I can't use administrator command, and have to requiring sudo? can't I just make my account at the same level as root account?
- you need to go into recovery mode to reset the root password. -- but the recovery mode is hard to access using virtual machine boot (pressing shift at just THE right time). is there any other way to change the root password?

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong call. The password works. So you just need to use the sudo command before your actual command. The terminal will asks you about your account password, and that's equal to the root password. This question is resolved.